# Why is Python's shutil.which() not working?

Tags: python, shutil, blast

I'm trying to see if `shutil.which()` works for finding the `blastn` command from NCBI's BLAST. Running `which blastn` on my terminal results in `/usr/local/bin/blastn`. However, if I do `shutil.which("blastn")`, it simply returns `None`. Searching for Python works fine, as `shutil.which("python")` returns `/usr/bin/python`. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is `os.environ['PATH']`? That's what it searches for executables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the environment in your shell has a different PATH than the environment within the Python runtime. There are many possibly causes, but it commonly happens because something in your `.bashrc` appends to PATH, which will be seen in shell but not by Python.

To check the environment in shell:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

To check the environment in Python:

```
import os
print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

You'll likely find that the shell's environment has the location of `blastn` in PATH and Python's doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was caused by having them equal, but the path containing the command I was searching was referred in the PATH variable with the home notation : ~/my/path rather than /home/username/my/path. Fixing this, the 'which' command worked correctly.